# Best way of coupling two different, non-inherited class parameters/variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

This is my first attempt at OOP, coming from a functional programming background, so I'm having a little trouble with designing coupled/linked objects. I'm trying to build a simple process simulation program that dynamically solves mass and energy balance equations, and I'm having trouble trying to get two different classes to communicate with each other.

I've declared two basic classes to describe my problem:

```
class Stream:
""" class that describes a fluid flow, with properties such as mass flow, temperature, pressure, etc."""    
    def __init__(self, massflow=1, temperature=0):
        self.m = massflow
        self.temperature = temperature

class Equip:
""" class that describes a process equipment, such as a heater """
    def __init__(self):
        self.StreamIn = Stream()
        self.StreamOut = Stream()
    def heating(self):
    """example method"""
        self.StreamOut.temperature = self.StreamIn.temperature + 100
```

So far so good. Each equipment can have multiple streams in or out, but for simplicity I'm trying out with one. Also, each stream connects one equipment with another.

Initially I created 2 Equip instances and "physically" connected them with a stream, so I'd have something like:

```
heater[1] = Equip()
heater[2] = Equip()
eq[2].StreamIn = eq[1].StreamOut
heater[1].heating()
eq[2].StreamIn = eq[1].StreamOut
```

This "works", but it feels... suboptimal. Each and every time I change the properties of a stream, I'd have to use this assignment, and I'd keep a "copy" of the stream data inside eq[1] and eq[2]. The stream object is kinda complex and it has several calculations so I'd like to avoid duplicating it if possible.

An alternative would be changing the Equip class to hold only an index to streams, and not the streams themselves.

```
class Equip:
""" class that describes a process equipment, such as a heater """
    def __init__(self, i_in, i_out):
        self.i_in = i_in
        self.i_out = i_out
    def heating(self, StreamIn, StreamOut):
    """example method"""
        StreamOut.temperature = StreamIn.temperature + 100

eq[1] = Equip(0, 1)
eq[2] = Equip(1, 2)

s[0] = Stream()
s[1] = Stream()
s[2] = Stream()

i_in = eq[1].i_in
i_out = eq[1].i_out
eq[1].heating(s[i_in], s[i_out])
```

Again, this "works" but not only the syntax is more annoying, if I create any other methods in Equip, I'll have to pass the stream every single time. Also, when I add multiple in/out streams in an equipment, I'd have to rewrite the whole code instead of the method.

The best solution that I've found so far would be to create a StreamList class, and rewrite the heating method to take the whole s list

```
...
def heating(self, StreamList):
    """example method"""
        StreamList[i_out].temperature = StreamList[i_in].temperature + 100
...
...

eq[1].heating(s)
```

The code is now cleaner and seems more flexible to future changes in the classes, but I don't know if passing the whole StreamList would have an impact on calculation speed (compared to passing a single Stream instance). In an iterative program with tens of equipments, hundreds of streams, each with different fluid properties and independent calculations being done each time a property changes, any gain in speed is welcome.

Ideally, the best solution would be to different Equip instances to "share" a Stream instance, and each change in this stream would reflect on both equipments. Is this even possible? Am I missing some hidden functionality to kinda "link" these two variable? Failing that, can you suggest a different approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you operating on indexes? Also, if you instantiate a `Stream` outside of the class, and hand the same instance to multiple classes, they will all be pointing at the same object. In your first example the second `eq[2].StreamIn = eq[1].StreamOut` is completely redundant.

Comment: Oh, by doing eq[2].StreamIn = eq[1].StreamOut they are already treated as the same object? I thought that by doing that, I would be creating a copy of eq[1].StreamOut inside eq[2].StreamIn, similar to how a = b works if a,b are numbers.Is this behavior exclusive to classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are missing here is mutability. If you hand a function, class, or method a mutable object, it will hand a reference to the same object, so there is no need to re-assign.

```
class Foo:
    pass
# create a mutable instance of Foo
foo = Foo()
# add an attribute to the instance
foo.bar = 5

def baz(a: Foo):
    a.bar = 10

baz(foo)
# what do you expect to print here?
print(foo.bar)
```

If you guessed `10` you would be correct. This is because objects in python are mutable by default.

Now to your example.

```
# As minimal as possible
class Stream:
    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature

class Equip:
    # takes 2 instances of Stream as arguments
    def __init__(self, stream_in: Stream, stream_out: Stream):
        self.stream_in = stream_in
        self.stream_out = stream_out

    def heating(self):
        # sets the temperature of instances assigned in the constructor
        self.stream_out.temperature = self.stream_in.temperature + 100

# create a list of 2 stream instances
streams = [Stream() for _ in range(2)]

# I'm making these refer to each other for example's sake
heater1 = Equip(streams[0], streams[1])
heater2 = Equip(streams[1], streams[0])

# this method will cause all references to streams[1]
# to increase by 100 more than streams[0] (100)
heater1.heating()
# this method will cause all references to streams[0]
# to increase by 100 more than streams[1] (200)
heater2.heating()

print(streams[0].temperature) # 200
print(streams[1].temperature) # 100

# And then we repeat
heater1.heating() # streams[1] to (300)
heater2.heating() # streams[0] to (400)

print(streams[0].temperature) # 400
print(streams[1].temperature) # 300
```

As you see they are still the same stream inside each of the objects.
There is no need to manually "link" them.
They are each referring to the same thing.

Comment: well, that explains it. My head is still wrapping up OOP after years of functional programming, so some basic concepts are still confusing, but this solves it. Thanks!